# Specific questions about how to use google calendar for groups

Tags: google-apps-script

I´d like to use the google calendar with a group. Could you please explain, whether its possible to make new slots for events solely accessible if every person to this calender is shared with is available (not busy) at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Freebusy: query](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query).

> Returns free/busy information for a set of calendars.

You can [try it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query#try-it).

If successful, here is the [response](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query#response)

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
  "timeMin": datetime,
  "timeMax": datetime,
  "groups": {
    (key): {
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": string,
          "reason": string
        }
      ],
      "calendars": [
        string
      ]
    }
  },
  "calendars": {
    (key): {
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": string,
          "reason": string
        }
      ],
      "busy": [
        {
          "start": datetime,
          "end": datetime
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```